# Fatal unable to connect to github.com while doing git pull origin master. I am upgrading floodlight to v 1.2

Tags: git, github, sdn, openflow

I installed Floodlight v1.1
When i try to upgrade it shows

```
$ git pull origin master

fatal : unable to connect to github.com
github.com[0: 20.207.73.82]errno = connection timed out
```

how to solve this error